# java interact with payshield 9000

Tags: java, hsm

Is it possible to build java application that can be used to verified
pin based on its pan, and change the pin if the customer need it. My company use thales payshield 9000..?

I can only connect through the hsm via ip and port

```
   private String HSM_IP = "10.100.2.4";
   private String HSM_PORT = "9998";
   private Socket socket = null;    

    try{
        socket = new Socket(HSM_IP,HSM_PORT);
        socket.connect();
        System.out.println("Connection Success");
    }catch (IOException iex){
       System.out.println("Connection Failed : " + iex.getMessage());
    }
```

I don't have any idea how to validate the pin entered by the customer , and change the pin if customer need it. Please help me, or tell me what I need to know first....thank you. (I'm sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

You could connect Thales HSM with Tcp and send commands to verify your PinBlock Data. HSM does not check nor understand your choice of language. You could check Thales documentation  "Command Reference Manual" to inspect details.

There are different commands to verify your PIN data:

Verify a PIN Using the IBM Method

Verify a PIN Using the IBM Method

Verify a PIN Using the VISA PVV Method

Verify a PIN Using the VISA PVV Method

Verify a PIN Using the Diebold Method

Verify a Terminal PIN Using the Comparison Method

Verify an Interchange PIN Using the Comparison Method

Translate a PIN and PIN Length

Comment: thank you for your answer. i decide to use host command "DU" for verify old pin and then generate new offset if the old pin is correct